# Jhipster: Could not contact UAA to get public key

Tags: jhipster

I cannot connect to UAA server. i'm deploying jhipster registry with eureka and UAA server in a remote server. and my microservices in my local machine in dev profile. i couldnt access to uaa public key. i changed the ip address in application-dev.yml but no result

Comment: Using dev or prod profile ? Can you see all apps (uaa and microservices) in the registry dashboard ? Did you edit the application properties in central-config for `native` configuration or git repository for `git` configuration used as environment source by the registry like documented here : https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/#-application-configuration-with-spring-cloud-config

Comment: Prod for Uaa and Dev for microservices. i can see all my microservices in registry. i'm running registry and uaa with docker in the same machine. and my microservices in other machine. I tried to get the key with postman and it works but with the same config the microservice could not contact UAA to get public key. i changed the public-key-endpoint-uri in application-dev.yml and i set the ip address of the uaa server but id didn't work